# Compare multiple columns in 2 sheets and return another column

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have some data of countries, states and cities. There are total of around 3 million rows.

```
`Country`  `City`        `AccentCity`  `Region`  `Population`  `Latitude`  `Longitude`
af     amir kalay       Amir Kalay      16        0             34.6333     70.3333 
ad     aixas            Aixas           06        0             42.4833     1.4667 
and lot more records
```

I divided it into 7 files to save it in csv. As you can see, it is showing region numbers and not region names. However, I found another file, which gives, as you can see below, 2-digit country code, region number and region name.

```
country,Region,State
AD,02,"Canillo"
AD,03,"Encamp"
AD,04,"La Massana"
AD,05,"Ordino"
AD,06,"Sant Julia de Loria"
AD,07,"Andorra la Vella"
AD,08,"Escaldes-Engordany"
AE,01,"Abu Dhabi"
```

How can I match these region numbers and region names so that every city shows the region name in front of it? Currently it shows the region number. Is there any query or formula which can match the country code and region number in both sheets and put the region name in front of the city name?

Comment: You could try using index() and match() or vlookup(). Then show what you have achieved.

Comment: @SolarMike Can you tell me the formula to use?

Comment: You can see an example of vlookup in the answer given - so what have you tried for index() and match()

Comment: If you did a search orn here, you would find this question and answer for example : https://stackoverflow.com/q/48554091/4961700

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption you want to show the column headed 'State' as a new column in the first table with Latitude/Longitude.

You can put the Country/Region/State in a new tab (Sheet4 in this example), add a column in front and concatenate columns B&C (=b2&c2) the country/region in column A.

In a new column use VLOOKUP concatinating country/Region of the first table finding the key in Sheet4, and returning the fourth column - "State".

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UPPER(A1)&D1,Sheet4!A:D,4,FALSE),"Unknown")

Please be sure to keep the leading zeros of region when placing in Excel.